# Inner join update

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have following two tables
TAB_1

```
FID   T_NAME_1 NAME2
---------------------
```

TAB_2

```
FID   T_NAME_2   NAME3
----------------------
```

For all matching fid of tab_1 and tab_2 there are some miss- matched fields of T_NAME_1  and T_NAME_2, which should not be there. so I want to update t_name_1 of table tab_1 with all the miss-matched values of t_name_2.
I tried following query which returning an error

```
update tab_1 set t_name_1 = (  select  t2.t_name_2 from tab_2 t2 left join tab_1 t1 on 
t1.fid = t2.fid where t1.t_name_1 <> t2.t_name_2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
update tab_1 t1
   set t_name_1 = (select t2.t_name_2
                     from tab_2 t2
                    where t1.fid = t2.fid
                      and t1.t_name_1 <> t2.t_name_2)
 where exists (select 1
          from tab_2 t2
         where t1.fid = t2.fid
           and t1.t_name_1 <> t2.t_name_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
update tab_1 t1 set t_name_1 = (  select  t2.t_name_2 
                                  from tab_2 t2 
                                  where t1.fid = t2.fid 
                                  and t1.t_name_1 <> t2.t_name_2)
where exists (select *
              from tab_2 t2
              where t1.fid = t2.fid
              and t1.t_name_1 <> t2.t_name_2)
```